# Sequelize: $like though multiple included models

Tags: where-clause, sequelize.js, sql-like

We have an endpoint in API which filters and return events.

`event` has following relations:

- eventModel

  - audioModel

    - deviceModel
  - userModel

Which means that `event` is associated to one `audio` and one `user`, `audio` is associated to one `device`.

---

This is a shortened code snippet from the endpoint which filters events:

```
eventModel.findAndCountAll({
    where: { /*...*/ },
    include: [{
            model: audioModel,
            attributes: ['guid', 'measured_at'],
            where: { /*...*/ },
            include: [{
                model: deviceModel,
                attributes: ['guid', 'shortname'],
                where: { /*...*/ },
            }]
        },
        {
            model: userModel,
            attributes: ['guid', 'firstname', 'lastname', 'email'],
            where: { /*...*/ },
        },
    ]
});
```

Every model has `where` attribute which filter out items by dates, Nulls and some other stuff. I've cut, because it's not important in my case.

What I need is to add a `search` attribute which will filter events by multiple nested attributes:

`eventModel.guid` `$like` `search` **OR**
`deviceModel.guid` `$like` `search` **OR**
`deviceModel.shortname` `$like` `search` **OR**
`userModel.firstname` `$like` `search` **OR**
`userModel.lastname` `$like` `search`

My problem is that I cannot put `$like` into each `where` attribute inside included models, because in that case condition will work as **AND** but not **OR**.

Is there any way to implement such stuff without migrating to raw query?

Comment: Can u not make 3 queries with like clauses and trigger them together with promise.all
If you also need the include, then I doubt there would be a way to do it

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to do that without using the `RAW` query. Find below :

```
var condition = " eventModel.guid like '%"+searck_keyword+"%' ";
condition += " OR deviceModel.guid like '%"+searck_keyword+"%' "
condition += " OR deviceModel.shortname like '%"+searck_keyword+"%' "
condition += " OR userModel.firstname like '%"+searck_keyword+"%' "
condition += " OR userModel.lastname like '%"+searck_keyword+"%' "
```

and pass the condition in `where` like `where: [condition]` and removed the `where` of all included models